# Communication between a desktop app and a browser

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, desktop-application, communication

How can I implement a mechanism for communication between a desktop application and a browser, for example Firefox or Google Chrome.

Is there a platform independent solution or I need to implement it for each platform separately?

Answer (score 2):

The app either serve a webserver for the browser. or some other 3rd host would be the webserver, in which your application would communicate with the browser via-proxy (that is issue a request to the server 'Send the browser this data' ).

In addition, you would have to periodically check for updates from the server using AJAX or page refreshes due to the fact that the server cannot issue a command to the browser, only upon the browser request [This also possible through COMET or COMET-LIKE technology].